# How can I add section breaks to a form with only CSS?

Tags: html, css

This might not be possible, but I'm open to ideas for other solutions!

I'm using a WordPress plugin for a custom registration form. The problem is that the free version does not allow styling such as headlines and section titles. It does however allow you to embed CSS class into each input. Thus, I have set the form itself as `.registration_form` and currently all fields `.register_form_field`

I would like to tidy up the form slightly with titles or some other way to create noticeable section breaks that look nice, in order to achieve three sections (Login, Personal, Contact).

For example: If I have set a second CSS class on the first field Username to `.username_field` And added above the field `content:"Login Details"` with a small border.

However, I kinda failed because my aim was to put the border below the contents. Although; it might look better with a border top and bottom.

So, does anybody know how I can achieve this or do you have any other ideas to target the class `.username_field` purely with CSS in order to add a pretty section space / title before it?

Thank you.

```
.username_field {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.username_field::before {
    content: "Login Details";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0.5em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #31324E;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to include sample HTML in a functioning snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the border to be underneath "Login Details".

First of all, [you cannot use the `::before` pseudo-element with `input`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field).  So I assume the field is contained inside some container such as a `div`, and it's the container that actually has the `username_field` class.

In that case, I believe the problem is with the `height` and `vertical-align` properties you have set, so removing them should fix the problem:

```css
.username_field::before {
    content: "Login Details";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #31324E;
}
```

```html
<div class="username_field">
  <label for="field">Username</label><br>
  <input id="field">
</div>
```

Comment: Spot on Michael. height and vertical-align was the problem. Thanks for taking the time to point it out.